# Google Tag Manager drop down tracking not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have return below code for drop down tracking. It is working fine on fire fox but not in chrome browser.Data to fire only when drop down text is selected

```
          jQuery("body").on("click",'#selectoption    option[value=option1]').click(function(){

try {
    var label = "";
        dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'error-click',
        'category': 'text1',
        'action': 'text2',
        'label': 'text3'});
} catch (err) {}
```

});

jQuery("body").on("click",'#selectoption option[value=option2]').click(function(){

```
try {
    var label = "";
        dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'error-click',
        'category': 'text4',
        'action': 'text5',
        'label': 'text6'});
} catch (err) {}
```

});

below code snapshot[image]

I have use below code for chrome but is firing twice in chrome and not working in firefox

```
jQuery('#selectoption').change(function () {

try {
    var label = "";
        dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'error-click',
        'category': 'text4',
        'action': 'text5',
        'label': 'text6'});
} catch (err) {}
```

});

Can any assist with right code Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine with my implementation in both of the browser

```
jQuery('#selectoption').change(function () {
    try {
        var label = "";
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'error-click',
          'category': 'text4',
          'action': 'text5',
          'label': 'text6'});
    } catch (err) {}
});
```

There may be some other issue. Have any clicks bind through GTM?